# JComboBox Current value used

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, handler, jcombobox

How come each time I click the submit button on my code it keeps on giving me the hourly string value?  even if the item in my JComboBox has the current value of weekly? how would I fix this?

The code for my ComputeWindow

```
public class ComputeWindow extends JFrame{

        private JLabel payRate,employeeID,payType,gWage;
        private JTextField  empRate,idTxt,gWageTxt;
        private JComboBox rateChooser;
        private JPanel panel;
        private JButton generate;

        public ComputeWindow(){

            super("Gross Wage");
            setSize(300, 150);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            String[] employeeType = {"Hourly","Bi Weekly","Weekly","Base"};

            employeeID = new JLabel("Employee ID: ");
            payRate  = new JLabel("Employee Rate: ");
            payType = new JLabel("Pay Type: ");
            gWage = new JLabel("Gross Wage");
            empRate = new JTextField(10);
            idTxt = new JTextField(10);
            gWageTxt = new JTextField(10);
            generate = new JButton("Compute!");
            rateChooser = new JComboBox(employeeType);
            panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));

            panel.add(employeeID);
            panel.add(idTxt);
            panel.add(payRate);
            panel.add(empRate);
            panel.add(payType);
            panel.add(rateChooser);
            panel.add(gWage);
            panel.add(gWageTxt);
            panel.add(generate);
            add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            String Option =(String)rateChooser.getSelectedItem();

            GenerateHandler generateHandler = new GenerateHandler();
            generate.addActionListener(generateHandler);
            generateHandler.setOption(Option);
        }   
    }
```

and for the handler here it is

```
private class GenerateHandler implements ActionListener{

        String option;

        public void setOption(String option){
            this.option = option;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(option =="Hourly"){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,option);
            }else if(option == "Weekly"){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,option);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

any suggestions? on how would I fix this? or it will return or show me the current value that is being used in my JComboBox?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code as follows:

```
GenerateHandler generateHandler = new GenerateHandler(rateChooser);
```

and

```
private class GenerateHandler implements ActionListener{
    JComboBox rateChooser;

    public GenerateHandler(JComboBox rateChooser){
        this.rateChooser = rateChooser;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String Option =(String)rateChooser.getSelectedItem();
        if("Hourly".equals(option)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,option);
        }else if("Weekly".equals(option)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,option);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Above code will solve your solution, but this is not a good practice to extend JFrame, specially JSomething ... and initialize everything in a constructor the way it is done.

Comment: then how should I do it?? or what's the proper way to do it??

Comment: in a meeting :( right now, it should take some time to exmplain. but as a beginning this is okey for exploring

Comment: it's okay i'll wait, I don't have much idea yet with GUI's i am just starting out

Comment: You will have to replace the == checks by equals checks or none of the checks will return true

Comment: what's the difference between them??

Comment: @Robin thanks for the catch ;). Updated the answer. And to know the difference take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5286330/511736