# Is it possible to use string contents as an image modifier for painting?

Tags: java, string, image, graphics, paint

I am currently working on a small Java game in eclipse, and am knee deep in a few thousand lines of code. Right now, I am specifically attempting to use a String's contents to paint an image, and am wondering if it is possible. If it is it would save me at least a few hundred lines of individual variables for each image.

Pasting the whole program would more than likely prove counter productive due to the length, so I will merely demonstrate what I am attemtping.

What I am attempting to do:

```
ImageIcon ladder = new ImageIcon (getClass ().getResource ("ladder.png"));
floorContents [currentX] [currentY] = "ladder";

public void paint (Graphics g)
{
     if (floorContents [currentX] [currentY] != "none") // painting item where standing
     {
         floorContents[currentX][currentY].paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
     }
}
```

Essentially I am attempting to get the program to see
this line:

```
floorContents[currentX][currentY].paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
```

as this:

```
ladder.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
```

If at all possible. This would save me from having to write in each image item seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each image in a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) keyed by the string

```
imageMap.put("ladder", new ImageIcon (getClass ().getResource ("ladder.png")));

//...

imageMap.get(floorContents [currentX] [currentY]).paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
```

Of course, you should key to see if the map contains the key first, or if the value returned is null...

```
if (imageMap.containsKey(floorContents [currentX] [currentY]) {
    //....
}
```

of

```
ImageIcon image = imageMap.get(floorContents [currentX] [currentY]);
if (image != null) {
    //...
}
```

But that's up to you

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (floorContents [currentX] [currentY] != "none")
```

Should be more like:

```
 if (!floorContents [currentX] [currentY].equals("none"))
```

See [String comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286310/string-comparison-in-java) (and [about 500 more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[string]+[java]+comparison)) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I would kill use of strings altogether. "none" is code-smell for `null` if I ever saw it. Why even match on a `String` at all.

```
ImageIcon[][] floorContents;
ImageIcon ladder = new ImageIcon (getClass ().getResource ("ladder.png"));
floorContents[currentX][currentY] = ladder;


public void paint (Graphics g) {
   if (floorContents [currentX] [currentY] != null) {
      floorContents[currentX][currentY].paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
   }
}
```