# What happen when we concatenate two strings

Tags: string, concatenation

I was expecting output true but i am getting output as a false Can any one explain me this?

```
String st = "mah";
        String st1 = "mah";
        String test = st + st1;
        String test1 = st + st1;
        System.out.println(test == test1);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the language you're using. That's the most important tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286310/string-comparison-in-java)

Comment: You haven't specified the language.
Assuming you're using java:
1. st + st1 returns a new object containing the "mahmah"
2. since st + st1 is called twice, it returns two different objects (maybe interning can sometimes make this statement invalid?)
3. you are using == which means (for objects) that unless both variables are "pointing" at the same object, you will get false.
(for example, if String test1 = test, the result becomes true)

But as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286310/string-comparison-in-java you should use the equals method to compare strings

Answer (score 0):

If the strings you're joining aren't compile time constants, you can't avoid creating a new string, because of String's immutability.
    try below-You will get true.

```
    final String st = "mah";
            final String st1 = "mah";
            String test = st + st1;
            String test1 = st + st1;
            System.out.println(test == test1);
```